# Cassandra scaling on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, benchmarking, ycsb, horizontal-scaling

After I successfully setup and run a Cassandra (v2.1) cluster I'm running some load tests to evaluate its performance using the YCSB library (https://github.com/jbellis/YCSB fork).

For my evaluation I use the same configuration on different sizes and number of EC2 nodes, however the performance is not really predictable, in contrast to the claims of the official datastax documentation where it supposedly scales linearly.

To be more precise, 2 x m3.large nodes and 4 x m3.large nodes have almost identical performance, when running the workloada with 100 or 200 threads and 100k or 1m operations. I use the EC2Snitch and 2 seeds nodes on a single region cluster. `commitlog_sync: batch` and 
`commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms: 50` are un-commented.

What am I doing wrong and what I might be missing?

Thanks

Comment: I realize this was a while back, but do you have the numbers that you were getting? were they reasonable for smaller number of nodes?  it's possible you were constrained on the client side.

Comment: From as far as I remember the numbers were around 4k ops/s. I haven't tried smaller nodes on AWS but again if my memory serves me well, running with 3 vagrant boxes locally gave me around 1k ops/s. I have indeed thought of client side constrains and my thinking when starting this thread was mostly about how to get around this and learn what would be the best way to set up a consistent and reliable benchmarking system. I have read a few articles regarding that but they were mostly focused on having a common testing scheme and realize what you test, rather than how to push from a client side.